# What are basic parameters that need to be tracked, recorded or monitored in diabetic patients?

Tags: diabetes, biological-parameter

I want to make a diabetes app to assist diabetic patients (not replace a doctor). What are basic parameters that a diabetic needs to track, record, or monitor? For example maybe: BMI, BMR, etc.

Comment: I think that this question (and probably your approach to designing this app) should be redefined. Diabetes is a **very serious condition. There is no way that an app can replace consultations with a doctor!** This would be **very dangerous.** You could design an app that would help patients keep track of their routine, progress, therapy etc. which they could use when they consult with their doctor to answer the doctor's questions e.g. But a phone can't replace a doctor, no matter how "smart" it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question needs reframing. Instead of asking about an app, ask about what are the basic parameters a diabetic need to monitor, and then it can be fit better to the website.

Comment: I am voting to close because even if the question is considered on topic, it's simply too broad. This (finding out what info needs to go into an application) is my day job, and it takes hundreds of hours of talking to users and other stakeholders. It is not possible to be answered in a Stack Exchange website. It is similar to somebody coming and saying "I want to direct a TV sitcom about a hospital, could please somebody give me a script for the first season". It is simply not doable.

Comment: for example if a user visited doctor and he want to save his record for diabetes monthly or weekly. what will he do? for example doctor said to take these tablets in morning , evening. Should he hire a robot for reminder? i am just giving an example.

Comment: i have seen a person who diagnosed his cancer, so why not diabetes ?